# Updating profile permissions using apex code

Tags: security, profile

Hi I have around 500 profiles, for a particular profile i want to update its CRUD permissions. I want to do this through APEX code. Can i implement this?

Comment: Did you find a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

No, not from Apex directly. You would need to use the metadata API.

If you want to update one profile, easiest to use the UI.

If you want to update 500 then it might be worth investing some time exporting the XML of the profiles, amending it there, and saving it back. Profiles are notoriously tricky though, especially if other changes to the org are made whilst you are working.

Another approach to changing multiple profiles would be to use something like Selenium to script the clicking.

Comment: n.b. A handy reference to what SObjects can't be updated through APEX DML is here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_dml_non_dml_objects.htm?SearchType=Stem